# Where does JSF store request parameters?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, viewstate

I noticed in JSF, if you pass request parameters in initial GET request, e.g. /admin/userForm.jsf?id=1, after postback, if you stay on the same page (e.g. by return null in the action method), the URL changes to /admin/userForm.jsf. You can see the query string is no longer there. But I can still access the request parameter in subsequent postback even though it's not in the URL. Just wondering if someone can explain to me how/where does JSF store the initial request parameters? In viewstate?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This link http://jdevelopment.nl/stateless-stateful-jsf-view-parameters/ will give you enough idea about request parameters.

Comment: After inspecting the HTML codes generated by JSF, I think I can answer my own question. The request parameters are passed back to server by JavaScript parameters. See below for an example

onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('userForm'),{'userForm:j_idt55':'userForm:j_idt55','id':'3'},'');return false"

Comment: @user: that's only there if you explicitly used `<f:param name="id" value="#{param.id}">` inside the command link/button. So, you're doing it yourself, not JSF :)

Comment: Yes. You're right. I forgot that. Thanks.